QGIS count points layer to polygon layer that have the same field attribute
From a layer with point geometry 'POINTS' and a layer with polygon geometry 'POLY'. Both layers have a common attribute field "UNIONCODE".
To the 'POINTS' layer I apply the following expression for Geometry Generator that draws a line to the center of the polygon with which it shares the same code 'UNIONCODE'.
make_line($geometry,point_on_surface(geometry(get_feature('POLY','UNIONCODE',attribute($currentfeature,'UNIONCODE')))))


To count the joining points that join each polygon with the shared attribute, I use the following expression:
aggregate(
  layer:='POINTS',
  aggregate:='count',
  expression:="UNIONCODE",
  filter:=intersects(
    make_line($geometry, point_on_surface(geometry(get_feature('POLY','UNIONCODE',attribute($currentfeature,'UNIONCODE'))))),
    $geometry
  )
)


As you can see, this expression only counts the total points and does not filter for each different polygon.
I would like to count the unions that are generated for each different polygon with an expression for Geometry Generator applicable to Labels.

As you already have an attribute that identifies the polygon each point is assigned to, you can count the points, grouped by this value - simply:
count (@id, group_by:=UNIONCODE)


If you want to count based on the geometry (no. of points within each polygon), use this expression:
count (@id, group_by:=overlay_within ('POLY',@id)[0])

